# Show x tick label for every second tick using xticklabels from table

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am adding x tick labels to my plot, using `xtick=data` and `xticklabels from table`. How can I skip every second tick mark?

My code is below.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{./data/crash_1987_returns.csv}{\loadedtable};

\begin{axis}[
    width=17cm,
    height=7cm,
    grid=both,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    no marks,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\loadedtable}{Date},
    x tick label style={rotate=90},
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=5
    },
    scaled y ticks=false,
    legend style={at={(0.025,0.95)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel={Change (\%)},
    y label style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.01)}, anchor=south, rotate=-90}
]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{SP500, DIJA}{
    \addplot+[ultra thick] table [x expr=\coordindex, y=#1] {\loadedtable};
    \addlegendentry{S\&P 500};
    \addlegendentry{DIJA};
}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is per definition impossible with `xticklabels from table`.

Comment: @StefanPinnow what should I use instead of `xticklabels from table` ?

Comment: @lala_12: Maybe you can use tikzmath, indexed macros and a for-loop within tikzpicture. But, math engine is not very easy to code. I would recommend to generate a seperate table with a list of the ticks that you want to see the mark and use that table for the marks.